# Checking if username exist produces no error and an error

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, error-handling

I want to check if a username is taken before a user decides they want to change their username. For some reason when checking and pressing done, the error banner appears stating the username is already taken ( Even when I enter one that clearly isn't) and at the same time my print statement " Successfully changed username" prints in the console too. The username changes successfully in the database but since the error banner appears it prevents me from dismissing the pushed view controller.

I can't seem to figure out why the error shows no matter what.. Heres the code I've written..

```swift
 func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {


        let trimmedString = usernameTextField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+$", with: "", options: .regularExpression).lowercased()

        guard trimmedString != "" else {
            print("ERROR: Please enter a valid username")
            usernameChanged = false
            return
        }

        updatedUsername = trimmedString?.lowercased()
        usernameChanged = true


    }

 func updateUsername() {
        guard let updatedUsername = self.updatedUsername else { return }
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        guard usernameChanged == true else { return }

        let reference = Database.database().reference().child("activeUsernames")
        let query = reference.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: updatedUsername )


        query.observe(.value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in

            if DataSnapshot.exists() {

                print("Username already exists")
                self.errorBanner()



                } else {
                print("Username successfully changed")
                reference.child(currentUid).child("username").setValue(updatedUsername)

                USER_REF.child(currentUid).child("username").setValue(updatedUsername) { (err, ref) in

                    guard let userProfileController = self.userProfileController else { return }
                    userProfileController.fetchCurrentUserData()
                    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)


                }


            }

        })


    }


    @objc func handleDone() {


        view.endEditing(true)

        if usernameChanged {
            updateUsername()


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the `FirebaseRealtimeDatabase` API's.

`observe` is supposed to deliver realtime events, but what you need to check for username existence is just to read once (Please check how to do this here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#read_data_once)

So what you're seeing in your code, is basically you're getting confused by the value your set :)

Also few Swift suggestions though:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
// Here non-regex API is better
        let trimmedString = usernameTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaceAndNewline)
        guard trimmedString != "" else {
            print("ERROR: Please enter a valid username")
            return
        }
        updatedUsername = trimmedString?.lowercased()
    }

// Swift willSet / didSet is better
var updatedUsername: String? {
    willSet {
       if updatedUsername != newValue {
           usernameChange = true
       }
    }
}
var usernameChanged: Bool
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for linking me to the correct source. Also thank you very much for the suggestions I will change the code to that!